# Using STAR shared memory module in Snakemake for sequential alignment tasks

Tags: python, shared-memory, snakemake

I'm writing a Snakemake pipeline for scRNAseq sequence processing which uses STAR as the alignment tool.

Loading genome index into the memory for each alignment job is very time-consuming. Since I have a lot of memory at my disposal, I figure that it is feasible to use the "shared memory" module from STAR. With it I can load the genome into the memory and keep it there until all the jobs are done.

With shell this is very easy to achieve, for example [here](https://biohpc.cornell.edu/doc/RNA-seq_2020_exercise1.html).

But chianing it in a Snakemake pipeline seems a non-trivial task, especially that the STAR "shared memory" module doesn't require any input or output anything. For example, I tried:

```
# Not full pipeline
rule umi_tools_extract:
    input:
        read1="{sample}_R1.fq.gz",
        read2="{sample}_R2.fq.gz",
        whitelist="whitelist.txt"
    output:
        "{sample}_R1_extracted.fq.gz"
    shell:
        """
        umi_tools extract --bc-pattern=CCCCNNNN \
                          --stdin {input.read1} \
                          --read2-in {input.read2} \
                          --stdout {output} \
                          --read2-stdout --filter-cell-barcode --error-correct-cell \
                          --whitelist={input.whitelist}
        """

rule STAR:
    input:
        fq="{sample}_R1_extracted.fq.gz",
        genomeDir=directory("/path/to/genome")
    output:
        "{sample}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
    threads:32
    shell:
        """
        STAR --runThreadN {threads} \
             --genomeLoad LoadAndKeep \
             --genomeDir {input.genomeDir} \
             --readFilesIn {input.fq} \
             --readFilesCommand zcat \
             --limitBAMsortRAM 20000000000 \
             --outFilterMultimapNmax 1 \
             --outFilterType BySJout \
             --outSAMstrandField intronMotif \
             --outFilterIntronMotifs RemoveNoncanonical \
             --outFilterMismatchNmax 6 \
             --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
             --outFileNamePrefix {wildcards.sample}_
        """
... ...

rule STAR_unload:
    input:
        genomeDir=dirctory("/path/to/genome")
#    output:  ## Put something here??
#        ""
    shell:
        """
        STAR --genomeLoad Remove \
             --genomeDir {input.genomeDir} \
        """
```

But obviously this wouldn't work. I'm thinking of putting a dummy output in the `STAR_unload` rule and feed it into rules downstream of `STAR` so that the `STAR_unload` will be triggered after alignment jobs are done.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question should probably be moved to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/!

Comment: Hi @KonradRudolph Before submitting the question, I did a keyword search with "STAR shared memory snakemake" on both SO and Bioinformatics StackExchange and found SO has more related activities, so I posted it here :-) Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Such a search is probably misleading: Stack Overflow has vastly more contents than the Bioinformatics site, but (a) much of that content is historical and (b) your question will be drowned in a sea of other topics, whereas Bioinformatics has more focus on such questions. So the chance of getting a good answer is a lot higher on the latter, even though it has vastly less overall activity. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the STAR "shared memory" module doesn't require any input or output anything

I'm not familiar with STAR and the shared memory option, but the issue about input/output can be easily resolved using dummy, flag files that signal a step is done. E.g.:

```
rule index_genome:
    input:
        fa= 'genome.fa',
    output:
        done= touch('index.done'),
    shell:
        r"""
        STAR index ... {input.fa} 
        """

rule load_genome:
    input:
        'index.done',
    output:
        touch('loading.done'),
    shell:
        r"""
        STAR --genomeLoad LoadAndExit --genomeDir ...
        """

rule align:
     input:
         fq= 'reads.fastq',
         idx= 'loading.done',
     output:
         ...
     shell:
         r"""
         STAR ...
         """

rule unload_genome:
    # Delete the loading.done flag file otherwise subsequent runs of the pipeline 
    # will fail to load the genome again if STAR alignment is needed.
    input:
        # Generic function that aggregates all alignment outputs
        bams= get_files(),
        idx= 'loading.done',
    output:
        "logs/STARunload_Log.out"
    shell:
        r"""
        STAR --genomeLoad Remove \
             --genomeDir {input.genomeDir} \
             --outFileNamePrefix logs/STARunload_
        rm {input.idx}
        """"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround similar to @dariober's solution, using dummy files.

Using the `--outFileNamePrefix` flag in `STAR`, I can create a dummy log file during genome unload. But this is not as clean as dariober's answer as STAR creates three files `Log.final.out`, `Log.out`, and `Log.progress.out` automatically.

```
# Unload STAR genome index
rule STAR_unload:
input:
    # Generic function that aggregates all alignment outputs
    bams=get_files(),
    genomeDir=directory("/path/to/index")
output:
    "logs/STARunload_Log.out"
shell:
    """
    STAR --genomeLoad Remove \
         --genomeDir {input.genomeDir} \
         --outFileNamePrefix logs/STARunload_
    """

rule some_downstream_step:
input:
    bam="Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
    dummy="logs/STARunload_Log.out"
output:
    "genes_assigned.bam"
shell:
    """
    ... ...
    """
```

Comment: Note that when you unload the genome you should also delete the `loading.done` flag file. I've edited my answer to add rule `unload_genome`.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could also mark the loading.done flag file as temporary? i.e. `temp(touch('loading.done'))`.